# Access log entries are not logged in istio sidecar for ingress traffic

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy, servicemesh

I have alb ingress which routes its traffic to istio-ingressgateway.

From there I have a gateway:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: "X-gateway"
  namespace: dev
spec: 
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "dev.xxx.com"
```

Also I have the virtual service in place:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vs-istio-ingress
  namespace: dev
spec:
  gateways:
    - X-gateway
  hosts:
    - "dev.xxx.com"
  http:
     - route:
        - destination:
            host: serviceX
            port:
              number: 8080
```

From there I have the service defined:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: serviceX
  labels:
    app: appX
spec:
  selector:
    app: podX
  ports:
    - port: 8080
```

I have access log enabled in the operator by setting:

```
spec:
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
```

The issue is when I hit the service from the ingress, the ingressgateway itself has the access log entry there, but not the sidecar of the service! (it's single pod), however, when the request is coming to the service via one of the service mesh the log entry is there in sidecar proxy access log.

Istio version is : 1.10.0
k8s version is : v1.21.4

Comment: I think missing from the doc is setting the log level eg, the values you see with `istioctl -n <namespace> proxy-config log deployment/<deployment_name>`, but I am not sure which needs to be adjusted for access logs.

Comment: The request are being sent using curl. How the service is being invoke

Comment: @jordanm, I don't think access log has any log level, it's not even a field in the log entry of access log.

Comment: The requests are being sent via the browser or curl or anything, by then end of the day they are routed from alb ingress to istio ingressgateway, everything is working perfectly fine but the only missing part is ingress traffic access log entries in pod sidecar.

Comment: @AladdinNawasreh I see `http` and `http2` that might be relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service port name should be there:

```
spec:
  selector:
    app: podX
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
```

This solves the issue.